# c++ pointers and variable scope

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to create a tree structure using some handler functions that are called while reading a stream. I think the problem is that my variables are created in the function's scope and disappear when the function ends, leaving pointers that point to nothing.

I am not sure what approach to take to keep the objects in memory, whilst still allowing the tree to be scalable.

I have made a simplified version of the code: it compiles and runs but the parent-child relationships of the 'Segment' objects are all wrong.

```
class Segment
{
public:
    Segment* parent;
    list<Segment*> children;
    string name;
};

void OpenSegment(Segment* p_segCurrentseg);
void CloseSegment(Segment* p_segCurrentseg);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Segment parent;
    parent.name="parent";
    Segment* p_segCurrentseg=&parent;
    OpenSegment(p_segCurrentseg);
    OpenSegment(p_segCurrentseg);
    OpenSegment(p_segCurrentseg);
    CloseSegment(p_segCurrentseg);
    return 0;
}

void OpenSegment(Segment* p_segCurrentseg)
{
    Segment child;
    child.name="child";
    p_segCurrentseg->children.push_front(&child);
    child.parent=p_segCurrentseg;
    p_segCurrentseg=&child;
}

void CloseSegment(Segment* p_segCurrentseg)
{
    p_segCurrentseg=p_segCurrentseg->parent;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it compiles for you but it certainly doesn't compile for me. At any rate, it looks like you need to use `new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of problems in your code.

1. You are passing `p_segCurrentseg` by value and assigning to another pointer. This has no effect on the variable in the calling function.
2. As you already suspected, you are trying to assign `p_segCurrentseg` to point to a variable that will be gone when you return from the function.

What you can do:

1. Pass `p_segCurrentseg` by reference to a pointer.
2. Create an object from the heap and assign `p_segCurrentseg` to point to it.

Here's my suggestion for `OpenSegment`:

```
void OpenSegment(Segment*& p_segCurrentseg)
{
    Segment* child = new Segment;
    child->name="child";
    p_segCurrentseg->children.push_front(child);
    child->parent=p_segCurrentseg;
    p_segCurrentseg=child;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! you are legend

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the OpenSegment() method, particularly in these 3 lines:

```
Segment child;
child.name="child";
p_segCurrentseg->children.push_front(&child);
```

First, child is a local variable and  created on the stack.  You then push the address of child into your list.  When OpenSegment() returns, the address of child contains garbage since storage for local variables are deallocated.

The solution is to define child as a pointer to Segment, create it on the heap so it lives even after OpenSegment() returns.  You have to make sure to deallocate its memory too.  The proper place is to define a destructor for your Segment class.  In it, iterate through the list (of children segments) and deallocate the memory for each child.